# Why reported `failed to execute system command` when starting up Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What may be the reason for this error appeared during startup of Apache IoTDB? The error information is `[main] ERROR o.a.i.c.ServerCommandLine:63 - Failed to execute system command java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 0@group-000000000000: Failed to initRaftLog`.